# Issue with custom array ordering sequence Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am facing an issue with array ordering sequence. Need your help for desired result.

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 77, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 43, 51, 72, 89, 95, 100];
var b = [6,5,7,8,0,800,46,1,2,3,12,47,100,95];
var c = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= (a.length) - 1; i++) {
  var res = b.indexOf(a[i]);
  if (res > -1) {
   c.push(a[i]);
  }
}

document.write(c);
// I need same sequence of array B in reponse
// Desired Result
// 6,5,7,8,0,1,2,3,12,100,95
```

Comment: whats that with `obj`? you might simply do like `var c = b.filter(f => a.includes(f));`

Comment: @Redu it was mistakenly added on question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate array `b` instead of `a`:

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 77, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 43, 51, 72, 89, 95, 100];
var b = [6,5,7,8,0,800,46,1,2,3,12,47,100,95];
var c = [];

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  var res = a.indexOf(b[i]);
  if (res > -1) {
    c.push(b[i]);
  }
}

console.log(c.join(','));
```

A more functional solution is to use `Array#filter` on b:

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 77, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 43, 51, 72, 89, 95, 100];
var b = [6,5,7,8,0,800,46,1,2,3,12,47,100,95];

var c = b.filter(function(n) {
    return a.indexOf(n) !== -1;
});

console.log(c.join(','));
```

Comment: Thanks you save my day